# Can someone please help me with this pipelining question

Tags: digital-logic, time

[image]

A pipelined implementation of the circuit shown below is to be designed. The delays of the building
blocks are indicated inside circles. You are given buffers with a delay of 0.5 ns, and flip-flops with hold
time of 1 ns, setup time of 2.5 ns, and clock-to-Q delay of 2 ns. There is also a clock skew of 0.25 ns
per flip-flop going from input (left) to output (right). What is the minimum clock period (in ns) for which
the circuit will work.

The answer given by my instructor to this question is 8.25ns.

If the pipeplining is done such that a flipflop is placed before and after 4ns delay element, then the min. time counts to 4(t comb)+2.5 (t setup)+ 2(t clk-Q) -0.25 (t skew, l to r) =8.25.
This was the way that I came up to the given answer so as to ensure min time by pipelining. But what I can't understand is whether my approach is correct or not!

Comment: You need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question
you're having trouble with. In general, homework questions enjoy/suffer a
special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or
Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of
your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by
homework questions at the same time.

Comment: I have voted for re-opening but I a missing any reference to the timing of the building blocks. e.g. if each building block has a delay of 100ns you answer stays the same.

Comment: I think you may have gotten the number 8.25 wrong from the instructor. You should be looking at the largest combinational delay path you want to include in the pipeline. Otherwise your approach seems ok.